# How to print the result of a method outside of the method

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm trying to get ahold of the python class thing and I've written this little script which takes user input:

```
import sys


class Uttenhaler_setup:
    Fbol=5.01333e-10
    c=2.99792458e+8
    L=1000
    star_list=[]
    dusty_models=np.array([]) #array of all the dusty models
    incoming_stars='' #List of incoming stars


    def __init__(self):
        """Initiates the below modules."""
        self.star_catalog()
        self.InputKey()


    def star_catalog(self):
        """Imports the star catalog"""
        try:
            star_catalog=raw_input('Input pathname of stellar catalog: ')
            with open(star_catalog) as incoming_stars:
                for line in incoming_stars.readlines():
                    x=[item for item in line.split()]
                    self.star_list.append(x) #Appends the individual star-IDs to the empty array star_list.
            print 'Stars imported successfully.'
        except IOError:
            print 'Star import unsuccessful. Check that the star catalog file-path is correct. Program exiting now.'
            sys.exit()



if __name__=='__main__':
    Uttenhaler_setup()
```

I can't seem to find the right syntax to print the results of self.star_list outside of my method. Just looking for someone to point out my errors. Thanks.

Comment: When you say `my method`, is it inside or outside of the class `Uttenhaler_setup`?

Comment: Let me further exemplify how new I am to this...It's under the very last line of my code example. Outside(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have set up `star_list` as a class variable, not an instance variable. If you declare `star_list` as `self.star_list` within your `__init__` method you will be able to access `star_list` as follows:

```
tst = Uttenhaler_setup()
print(tst.star_list)
```

As you have things at the moment, you would need to access `star_list` with:

```
print(Uttenhaler_setup.star_list)
```

The difference is that a class variable is available to all instances of the class as a shared variable. If you change the value of a class variable, all instances of the class will see the change. However, an instance variable is local to a single instance or instantiation of a class. When you change an instance variable, the change is local to the particular instance of a class.

Normally you will want to make almost all your variables to be instance variables. Use class variables for things like constants that should be the same for all instances of your class.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like `my_stars = Uttenhaler_setup()` and then `print my_stars.star_list`.

Answer (score 0):

If inside the class `Uttenhaler_setup` you could:

```
print 'star_list=%r' % (self.star_list)
```

If outside the class `Uttenhaler_setup` you could:

```
var = Uttenhaler_setup()
print 'star_list=%r.' % (var.star_list)
```

Comment: "Not working" is not really helpful. What is actually happening?

Comment: Well for the second option I'm just getting a repeat of my first raw_input...like it started over. And the first option it's telling me 'star_list' is not defined.